# Angular - The infinite digest loop

Tags: angularjs

I'm currently facing the infinite digest loop error which I need some help/advice with.

So I've read [the docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$rootScope/infdig) as well as posts on StackOverflow and I think i understand the issue - if someone could also confirm - it's essentially because something in the `$scope` is changing a fair number of times.

Assuming what I understand above is correct - I'm unsure on how to solve this and any advice would be appreciated.

The code I have looks like this:

*HTML Side*

```
<ul class="no-bullet" ng-repeat=“person in persons”>
   <li>
     <div class="progressBar" ng-style="{background: styleBuilder(person.options)}"></div>
   </li>
</ul>
```

*And in my controller* 
(for context: `personsArray` is what is passed from the HTML side and the for loop is used to update an array that contains numbers into percentages so `['classA: 8', 'classB: 2']` becomes `['classA: 75', 'classB: 25']` (I've tested this and it works)

```
  $scope.styleBuilder = function (optionsArray){

    for (var index in personsArray){
      proportion = parseInt(personsArray[index].split(':')[1])/sumOfAllValues;
      if (isNaN(proportion) ){
        proportion = 0;
       }

       personsArray[index] = personsArray[index].substring(0, personsArray[index].indexOf(':'));
       personsArray[index] = personsArray[index] + ' : ' + proportion*100;

    }

}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Its required - so the data I get from `(person.options)` in that `ng-repeat` is used to style accordingly.

Comment: It goes away naturally - the error occurs at the line: `personsArray[index] = personsArray[index] + ' : ' + proportion*100;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in this line (in digest cycle as @Raulucco explained):

```
ng-style="{background: styleBuilder(person.options)}"
```

Try ng-init:

```
<li ng-init="bg = styleBuilder(person.options)">
   <div class="progressBar" ng-style="{background: bg}"></div>
</li>
```

Comment: Thanks - and would you say the reason below by Raulucco is correct to why this solution works?

Comment: @userMod2 Yes, `ng-init` creates scope property from function call result and no problem because of `$watch`

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you are changing the elements inside the array at the same time that you are looping through the array. Angular binds a watch to each options attribute because you are accessing the property inside the loop, you change it a digest cycle is fired.
To avoid it in this example do not change the options property just return the new style or loop through the array and change the options before assign it to the $scope.